# How to understand complicated typescript generic types?

Tags: angular, reactjs, typescript, rxjs6, typescript-generics

I was checking RxJS api documents. I always face problem in understanding the weird syntax written on the top, Which is like below as an example:

```
combineLatest<O extends ObservableInput<any>, R>(...observables: (O | ((...values: ObservedValueOf<O>[]) => R) | SchedulerLike)[]): Observable<R>
```

I wanted to understand this kind of syntax and further write it by my own.

**So, It will be great help if anyone explain what's going on in above example.**

Comment: Asking for tools, libraries, or off-site resources is off-topic in here

Comment: Ok. I am also asking for the explaination of code above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`function combineLatest<O extends ObservableInput<any>, R>(...observables: (O | ((...values: ObservedValueOf<O>[]) => R) | SchedulerLike)[]): Observable<R>`

Let's break it down.

Okay, that's a function

```
function combineLatest(args): Result
```

which takes some parameters and returns a result of type `Result`

But it's also a special  kind of functions called [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) functions. 
The purpose of generic is to provide meaningful type constraints between members.

```
function combineLatest<T>(args): Result
                      /\
           now it's a generic function
```

The `T` here is a *type variable* which allows us to capture the type the user provides, so that we can use that information later. For example, we can use `T` as the return type:

```
function combineLatest<T>(args): T
```

so that the following call:

```
combineLatest<string>(someParams) // returns `string`
```

will give us the result of type `string` since we explicitly set `T` to be `string`.

We can also use that `T` type variable for any of arguments of the function.

```
function combineLatest<T>(arg: T): T
```

And now we can use *type argument inference*:

```
combineLatest('someStr') // returns `string`
```

That is, we tells the compiler to set the value of `T` for us automatically based on the type of the argument we pass in. We've passed a `string` so that we've got a `string`.

We can use as many type variables as we want. And also we can call them whatever we want.

```
function combineLatest<Type1, Type2, ...>(...)
```

Generics are great and sometimes we want to make some actions with the parameters we've passed in:

```
function combineLatest<T>(arg: T): T {
  arg.name = arg.name.toLowerCase(); // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'T'
  return arg;
}
```

As you can see the compiler can't understand what type of `arg`. To remedy this we can denote the constraint for our `T` type variable with the help of `extends` operator:

```
interface ItemWithName {
  name: string;
}
function combineLatest<T extends ItemWithName>(arg: T): T {
  arg.name = arg.name.toLowerCase();
  return arg;
}
```

Now the compiler knows that arg has the `name` property of `string`.

---

Now let's come back to our initial declaration:

```
combineLatest<O extends ObservableInput<any>, R>(...): Observable<R>
```

We can see here that this function uses two type variables:

- `O` type variable which stands for Observable. It is constrained to be type of `ObservableInput<any>`
- `R` stands for Result

The result of the `combineLatest` function should be `Observable` of type `R`. For example we can force that type by calling this function like:

```
combineLatest<any, MyClass>(...)  // returns Observable<MyClass>
```

Now let's look at the parameters this function can take:

```
...observables: (O | ((...values: ObservedValueOf<O>[]) => R) | SchedulerLike)[]
```

We can see the [rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#rest-parameters) operator here. Let's simpify the expression above so we imagine something like:

```
...observables: CombinedType[]
```

This means that the `combineLatest` function can take zero and more arguments which will be later gathered together into one variable `observables`.

```
combineLatest();                 // without parameters
combineLatest(obs1);             // one parameter
combineLatest(obs1, obs2, ..etc) // many parameters
```

So what's the type of this parameter

```
           CombinedType

O | ((...values: ObservedValueOf<O>[]) => R) | SchedulerLike
```

It can be:

- the type of `O` type variable which is constrained to be type of `ObservableInput<any>` we discussed earlier
- **or** it can be function `(...values: ObservedValueOf<O>[]) => R` which takes zero or more parameters of type `ObservedValueOf<O>` and returns `R` type variable type. Note that this returned type can be used to infer the return type of the `combineLatest` function.
- **or** it can be type of `SchedulerLike` interface.

---

I think there shouldn't be any problem with understanding TypeScript type declarations if you split them into small pieces.

Comment: Great thanks @yurzui. This is really helpful explanation.